# Installing Quill with webpack yields parchment error

Tags: webpack, quill

I'm trying to install Quill with webpack and I followed the guide (http://quilljs.com/guides/adding-quill-to-your-build-pipeline/), but I'm getting an error where Parchment is not loading correctly:

```
ERROR in ./~/quill/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'parchment' in '/Users/myuser/Desktop/project/node_modules/quill'
 @ ./~/quill/core.js 1:0-34
 @ ./client/lib/Quill.js
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./client/components/mycomponent.js
 @ ./client/components/mycomponent.vue
 @ ./client/router/router.js
 @ ./client/app.js
 @ ./client/index.js
 @ multi client
```

I've double checked that `parchment` is `npm install`ed and I have the appropriate typescript loaders. Is there anything else I need to add to get webpack to recognize parchment in Quill?  My webpack config matches the recommended settings:

```
alias: {
      root: path.join(__dirname, '../client'),
      components: path.join(__dirname, '../client/components'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/styles'),
      lib: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/lib'),
      img: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/img'),
      'parchment': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/parchment/src/parchment.ts'),
      'quill$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/quill/quill.js')
    }
```